# SQL server 2012 Query migration

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, sql-server-2012

I want to migrate a MS Access query to SQL Server 2012.

I have migrated the query. In the MS Access query I have some calculations and conditions. My problem is how to use the when statement in SQL Server?

Here is the code from the MS Access query for the calculation. How can I translate this code to SQL Server?

```
Piece!Quatite*Commande!Prixunitaire+Wenn(Artikel!Prix<>0;(Artikel!prix*((Artikel!PST*1,01-Artikel!TVS)/100))/1000*[Quantite];0))
```

Comment: What is the actual problem you have? What you have you done so far?

Comment: the problem is how to use the iif statement in sql server,

Comment: The Code in sql server look like a comment, i post here another time the code in sql server

Comment: 'dbo.Tabelle1!Quantite*dbo.Tabelle2!Prixunitaire + iif (dbo.Tabelle_1!prix<>0 then dbo.Tabelle1!prix * ((dbo.tabelle1!TVS * 1,01 - Tabelle!VKR) / 100) / 1000 * dbo.Tabelle2.Quantite,  0 )'

Comment: You can use case statement instead of iff.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to guess that `wenn()` is `iff()`.  If so:

```
(Piece.Quatite * Commande.Prixunitaire) +
(case when Artikel.Prix <> 0
      then Artikel.prix *((Artikel.PST*1.01-Artikel.TVS) / 100)) /1000 [Quantite]
      else 0
 end)
```

However, it is unclear to me what this logic is really doing, because the value will be 0 if `Artikel.Prix` is 0.  If you are just checking for `NULL` values, you can use `coalesce()`:

```
(Piece.Quatite * Commande.Prixunitaire) +
coalesce(Artikel.prix *((Artikel.PST*1.01-Artikel.TVS) / 100)) /1000 [Quantite], 0)
```